# Block Scalar Style Folded multiline in YAML does not work in k8s via kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, multiline

I run `kubectl apply` for this file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
data:
  folded: >-
    {
      "field1": 1,
      "test2": "test"
    }

  literal: |-
    {
      "field1": 1,
      "test2": "test"
    }
  
  single-quoted:
    '{
      "field1": 1,
      "test2": "test"
    }'
```

And I get this result after running `kubectl describe`:

```
Data
====
folded:
----
{
  "field1": 1,
  "test2": "test"
}
literal:
----
{
  "field1": 1,
  "test2": "test"
}
single-quoted:
----
{ "field1": 1, "test2": "test" }
```

According to the documentation if I got things right I was expecting `folded` to be the same as `single-quoted`, i.e. in one line, but this does not happen. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually by design and due to extra spaces in json:

If you insert extra spaces at the start of not-the-first lines in Folded style, they will be kept, with a bonus newline. (This doesn't happen with flow styles.) [Section 6.5 of the YAML 1.2.2 spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#65-line-folding):

> In addition, folding does not apply to line breaks surrounding text
> lines that contain leading white space. Note that such a more-indented
> line may consist only of such leading white space.

This will work as I intended:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
data:
  folded: >-
    {
    "field1": 1,
    "test2": "test"
    }
```